# What is Elasticsearch snapshot retention rules recommended max_count?

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, snapshot

The Elasticsearch documentation states:

> A snapshot repository can safely scale to thousands of snapshots. However, to manage its metadata, a large repository requires more memory on the master node. Retention rules ensure a repository’s metadata doesn’t grow to a size that could destabilize the master node.
> [snapshot-retention-limits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-take-snapshot.html#snapshot-retention-limits)

What is a "safe" number of snapshots that will not destabilize the muster node?
I'm using version 8.2 and need to save between 1000-3000 snapshots in my repository, is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

They are no rules per say, it will depends on you use case.
But you can look at the [settings by default on elastic managed services](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-restoring-snapshots.html#ec-change-snapshot-count).

> The minimum number of snapshots must be at least 12, the maximum limit is 100.

But as you mentioned, if you have big master nodes you could have more.

Comment: I think these numbers are referring versions 7.5 and below

Comment: Agreed, I don't think there are recommandation ATM for version 7.5 and above. So to be on the safe side I would follow the previous recommandation.